# Get path to trace out a character in an iOS UIFont

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics, uifont, cgpath

Suppose I have a custom font "Foo" that I'm using in my iOS App.  I've added it to my project, plist, etc. and I'm able to render `UILabel`s and such with it just fine.

Now, if I want to find out a sequence of points that would "trace out" the letter 'P' in that font, how would I get that sequence of points?  For example, suppose I wanted to use a `CGPath` to draw the letter 'P' slowly like a plotter would ...

I just need a sequence of `CGPoints` in an array that if drawn as a path would draw a 'P'.

I realize that for some letters like 'T', this may not make sense, since the pen would have to be lifted to cross the 'T'.  So maybe I need a sequence of `CGPath`s ...

Any hints on how to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 43):

Going from the letter "P" to a sequence of points involves several steps.  You'll need to use Core Text.

1. Create a `CTFont`.  Since iOS 7, you can use a `UIFont` where a `CTFont` is needed (they are “toll-free bridged”). You can also create a `CTFont` directly from a `CGFont` using the `CTFontCreateWithGraphicsFont` function, or by name using `CTFontCreateWithName` (or using a few other methods).
2. Get the glyphs for the letter using the `CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters` function.  For the letter "P" there should be just one glyph.  For some characters in non-English scripts you may get multiple (combining) glyphs.
3. Use the `CTFontCreatePathForGlyph` function to get a `CGPath` for the glyph.
4. Use `CGPathApply` to enumerate the elements of the path.
5. Convert each line, quad curve, and cubic curve element of the path to a sequence of points.  Apple doesn't provide any public API for doing this.  You'll need to do it yourself.  For straight line elements it's easy.  For curve elements, you will need to do some research if you don't already know how to render a Bézier curve.  For example, see [convert bezier curve to polygonal chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247564/convert-bezier-curve-to-polygonal-chain).

We can experiment with this easily in a Swift playground:

```
import UIKit
import CoreText
import XCPlayground

let font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 64)!

var unichars = [UniChar]("P".utf16)
var glyphs = [CGGlyph].init(repeating: 0, count: unichars.count)
let gotGlyphs = CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters(font, &unichars, &glyphs, unichars.count)
if gotGlyphs {
    let cgpath = CTFontCreatePathForGlyph(font, glyphs[0], nil)!
    let path = UIBezierPath(cgPath: cgpath)
    print(path)
    XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.captureValue(value: path, withIdentifier: "glyph \(glyphs[0])")
}
```

Result:

```
<UIBezierPath: 0x7fbc89e0d370; <MoveTo {11.072000000000001, 23.808}>,
 <LineTo {11.072000000000001, 40.576000000000001}>,
 <LineTo {22.975999999999999, 40.576000000000001}>,
 <QuadCurveTo {30.560000000000002, 38.432000000000002} - {28.16, 40.576000000000001}>,
 <QuadCurveTo {32.960000000000001, 32.192} - {32.960000000000001, 36.288000000000004}>,
 <QuadCurveTo {30.560000000000002, 25.920000000000002} - {32.960000000000001, 28.096}>,
 <QuadCurveTo {22.975999999999999, 23.808} - {28.16, 23.744}>,
 <Close>,
 <MoveTo {4.992, 45.695999999999998}>,
 <LineTo {4.992, 0}>,
 <LineTo {11.072000000000001, 0}>,
 <LineTo {11.072000000000001, 18.687999999999999}>,
 <LineTo {25.024000000000001, 18.687999999999999}>,
 <QuadCurveTo {35.488, 22.208000000000002} - {31.936, 18.623999999999999}>,
 <QuadCurveTo {39.039999999999999, 32.192} - {39.039999999999999, 25.792000000000002}>,
 <QuadCurveTo {35.488, 42.143999999999998} - {39.039999999999999, 38.591999999999999}>,
 <QuadCurveTo {25.024000000000001, 45.695999999999998} - {31.936, 45.695999999999998}>,
 <Close>
```

[image: P glyph path]

Comment: @RobMayoff Excellent answer! Just what I was also looking for! Since you seem to know your CGPaths, do you know how I could add a line to the just created path? Say back to the starting point for example. Simply adding: `let pathP = CGPathCreateMutableCopy(CGPathCreateMutableCopy(cgpath))
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathP, nil, 0, 0)`doesn't seem to work.`

Comment: What does “doesn't seem to work” mean? You need to post a new question containing your code, the output (of dumping your modified path), and explaining what is wrong with the output.

Comment: @RobMayoff http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37088660/swift-how-to-add-points-to-a-closed-cgpath

Comment: I am using your code in my project,and i got letter "P", but it was flipped. I printed my layer contentsAreFlipped property, and it returns true. How can i fix this issue?                                                                                                                                                  let line : CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
      line.path = path.cgPath
            line.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
            line.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            line.position = self.view.center
            self.view.layer.addSublayer(line)

Comment: It's fixed i added this code line.isGeometryFlipped = true.

Comment: i want to do the same thing but reversed, i just want to extract the drawn path into text/glyph. how can i do that ? please help ?

Answer (score 4):

rob's answer updated for swift 4 + vertical flipping for CoreGraphics uses an inverted coordinate system :

```
    var unichars = [UniChar]("P".utf16)
    var glyphs = [CGGlyph](repeating: 0, count: unichars.count)
    let gotGlyphs = CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters(font, &unichars, &glyphs, unichars.count)
    if gotGlyphs {
        let cgpath = CTFontCreatePathForGlyph(font, glyphs[0], nil)!
        var inverse = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1).translatedBy(x: 0, y: -cgpath.boundingBox.height - 1)
        let path = UIBezierPath(cgPath: cgpath.copy(using: &inverse)!)
        print(path)
```

Answer (score 3):

For those who are looking the same solution in Objective C

```
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:64];
    CGFontRef fontref = CGFontCreateWithFontName((__bridge CFStringRef)font.fontName);
    NSString *unichars = @"I";
    CFStringRef yourFriendlyCFString = (__bridge CFStringRef)unichars;
    CGGlyph glyphs = CGFontGetGlyphWithGlyphName(fontref, yourFriendlyCFString);
    CTFontRef fontCT = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)font.fontName, font.pointSize, NULL);
    CGPathRef cgpath = CTFontCreatePathForGlyph(fontCT, glyphs, nil);
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath:cgpath];
    NSLog(@"Complete path For p is %@", path);
    CGPathApply(cgpath, (__bridge void * _Nullable)(bezierPoints), MyCGPathApplierFunc);
    NSLog(@"Points on path %@", bezierPoints);
    for(NSValue *point in bezierPoints){

       //Do your work
    }
```