# How do I discretize an SVG path with Java?

Tags: java, svg

In Java, how can I read in the `d` attribute of an SVG path, and discretize it such that all Bezier curves are properly subdivided into discrete points, allowing me to specify a threshold to account for sharp angles?

The only solution I've found after a ton of searching is to use Apache Batik to traverse the path in short intervals, and sample points uniformly, but that generates a bunch of unnecessary points along straight lines and doesn't handle the case of sharp angles.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented an algorithm to convert a quadratic bezier into a set of straight lines (vertices) in Javascript a while back. [Its here in action](http://www.iscriptdesign.com/?sketch=iPath/polybezier.jsvg)

It's not Java but it should not be too hard to convert, You should filter out the bezier curves yourself by regexing on `[Q,q,C,c,S,s]`

Some discription is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247564/convert-bezier-curve-to-polygonal-chain).