# Convert all svg elements into lines

Tags: c#, svg

I am using `XmlDocument` to extract `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, `y2` of `line` from a svg file. Then I have c# move the mouse to paint it somewhere on the screen using `mouse_event((int)(MouseEventFlags.LEFTDOWN), 0, 0, 0, 0);` and others.

Now with `x1` = `x2` and `y1` <> `y1` and `x1` <> `x2` and `y1` == `y1` that's a simple loop for mouse coordinates. With `x1` <> `x2` and `y1` <> `y2`, it gets more complicated, but still feasible. Yet with `M 26.029437251522861,59.970562748477143 A 24,24 0 1,1 43,67` and similar, this gets much more tedious.

How do I convert a svg will all kinds of strokes(just strokes, no gaussian blur or other effects) to line commands or especially `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, `y2` of line to paint them?

Comment: Thanks. But this is not c#.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247564/convert-bezier-curve-to-polygonal-chain and if you are using c# then https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-flatten-a-curved-path-into-a-line may have some interest